# How to turn from command to insert mode at the end of my elisp interactive script?

Tags: evil, insert

I am using Evil (Vi keybindings) in Spacemacs.

Let's say I have something like that:

```
(defun myfunc-org-insert-custom-stuff ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "This is custom stuff "))
```

but I would like to change the cursor from command to edit/insert mode, so I need to add some command after `(insert "This is custom stuff ")` so I am able to continue writing right away without the need to press `a` for jumping into insert mode.

The problem is I don't know what function will do that.

Any idea how to do that in Elisp?

Comment: I am using Spacemacs with Vim mode. Forgot to mention that. I am sorry. In Vim `a` will bring you back to insert mode from command mode. There are other ways like `i` but that's beside the point.

Comment: @phils Maybe it is Evil mode specific problem? Right now if I run this function I will stay in the command mode (the cursor is a rectangle block and not an I-beam) - because I triggered the function via a keybinding sequence and when I do that I have to be in a command mode (the rectangle block cursor).

Comment: Please update the text and tags to show that it is a question about Evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the function `evil-insert-state`. You could also use `evil-insert` or `evil-append` (which in Spacemacs you could find by using SPC h d k), but they take an argument, for which then you probably would like to use 0 or nil.

If you'd like to have `evil-append` like functionality, then I am not sure what is recommended, but I would probably use

```
(evil-insert-state)
(forward-char)
```

Comment: (evil-insert-state) is it! Thank you.